# How to open a text (.txt) file from SAS in R?

Tags: r, sas

I have a text (.txt) file that apparently was created on SAS. I have no idea how SAS works, but I need to open the text file in R so it reads as a dataframe with variables names and all.

The file can be downloaded here: https://www.ibge.gov.br/estatisticas/downloads-estatisticas.html?caminho=pense/2009/microdados/ . It's a zip file called "PENSE_2009_microdados.zip". There are 3 folders:

1. Dados - with "Base_Pense Completa_2009.txt"
2. Documentação - with the data dictionary
3. Input SAS - with a .csv file that I could not understand
4. A "read me" file that explains that the "Dados" folder contains the data and the "Documentação" folder contains "SAS's layout and reading input".

Does anybody know how to "transform" this data into a dataframe that makes sense? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need the translate the INFORMAT to the WIDTH needed by R to read a fixed position text file.  The ones with $ means the values are character strings.  The others are numbers.  The ones that have a value after the period is how many decimal places to imply when the string read does not include one.  Check the actual data to see whether or not you will need to imply the decimal point. If all of the values for vraibles like Q2B01P01I actually include the period in the 6 characters then you can ignore the decimal .2.  But if some have no period then SAS would divide the integer by 10**2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a fixed-width file, each line contains all variables in the documentation without spacing, and you provide the number of characters that make up each column.

The input sas file (this should be a .sas, not sure why it would be excel format) tells you the variable names and their formats/widths.

You can also get this from the documentation excel file plus the format of factor variables, eg, `B01P02` has 5 unique values coded 1 thru 5.

```
doc <- readxl::read_excel('PENSE_2009_microdados/Documenta‡ֶo/Dicionario_Base Pense_Completa.xls')
## the widths for each column
wid <- doc$TÉRMINO - doc$INICIO + 1

dat <- read.fwf(
  'PENSE_2009_microdados/Dados/Base_Pense Completa_2009.txt',
  ## also add variable names
  widths = wid, col.names = doc$CAMPO,
  # n = 1000,
  ## some options for importing NAs/trimming white space
  na.strings = c('NA', '.', ''), strip.white = TRUE
)

## add labels if wanted
dat <- Hmisc::upData(dat, labels = setNames(doc$DESCRICAO, doc$CAMPO))

str(dat)
```

Here is how you can use the formats. They are not standardized, so not all will be fixed this way:

```
x <- doc$DOMÍNIO[doc$CAMPO %in% 'B01P02']
# [1] "1- Branca\n 2- Preta(Negra)\n 3- Parda(Mulata) \n 4- Amarela(Oriental) \n 5- Indígena"

fmt <- read.table(text = x, sep = '-', strip.white = TRUE)
x_fmt <- factor(dat$B01P02, fmt$V1, fmt$V2)

table(old = dat$B01P02, new = x_fmt)
#    new
# old Branca Preta(Negra) Parda(Mulata) Amarela(Oriental) Indígena
#   1    309            0             0                 0        0
#   2      0          167             0                 0        0
#   3      0            0           436                 0        0
#   4      0            0             0                27        0
#   5      0            0             0                 0       30
```